# How to make two bar graphs side by side

Tags: r

I want to make graphs for `A.x` and `A.y` and make them side by side.

```
aggregate(A~ B , mydata, mean) 
aggregate(A~ B , mydata, sd) 
mydata2 <- aggregate(A~B , mydata, mean) 
mydata3 <- aggregate(A~B , mydata, sd) 

library(dplyr)
mydata2 <- mydata2 %>% dplyr::select(B = 1, A = 2) %>% dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ round(., 3))
mydata3 <- mydata3 %>% dplyr::select(B = 1, A = 2) %>% dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ round(., 3))
mydata4<- merge(x = mydata2, y = mydata3, by = 'B', all.x = TRUE)
mydata4

library(ggplot2)


ggplot(data=mydata4) + geom_bar(aes(x=B, y = A.x, fill=A.y), stat = "identity", position="dodge")
```

And the result wasn't what i want.

Here is a picture of `mydata4`.

[image]

My goal is to do something like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for one of the facet functions.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah      
 B   A.x   A.y
1     A 1.955 1.121
2   A/B 2.250 1.035
3 A/B/C 2.500 1.179
4   A/C 3.000 1.414
5     B 2.718 1.324
6   B/C 2.750 0.957
7     C 2.727 1.302

here it is. I am a beginner of R so i am clumsy to use tools of R. sorry

Comment: @IRTFM I added what i want to make in my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it you have to reshape your data.  Copy tjtis code

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata4 <- mydata4 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(A.x, A.y), names_to = 'name', values_to = 'val')

mydata4
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   B     name    val
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 A     A.x   1.96 
 2 A     A.y   1.12 
 3 A/B   A.x   2.25 
 4 A/B   A.y   1.03 
 5 A/B/C A.x   2.5  
 6 A/B/C A.y   1.18 
 7 A/C   A.x   3    
 8 A/C   A.y   1.41 
 9 B     A.x   2.72 
10 B     A.y   1.32 
11 B/C   A.x   2.75 
12 B/C   A.y   0.957
13 C     A.x   2.73 
14 C     A.y   1.30  

ggplot(data=mydata4) + geom_col(aes(x=B, y = val, fill=name), position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: I got the message that "Ignoring unknown parameters: stat"

Comment: Then I get only single graph.

Comment: What I want to make is one graph for A.x&B, and the other for A.y&B. And put together in one facet.

Comment: Got it.  Now check it

Comment: I got that graphs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Though the problem has been solved, can you please share snapshot of mydata2 and mydata3.  I still feel that instead of merge a Union of these two datasets could have solved your problem directly.